# Why do I need to press this button twice to display the data?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, swift4

I'm not understanding why I need to press the button twice in order to get the labels to populate with the gathered data. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong with the json parsing or if there is some kind of scope issue. I'm sure there is redundant code here, but I was trying everything I could think of and find through google.

```
import UIKit

struct SkillStats {
var Rank, Level, Experience: String
init(Rank: String = "", Level: String = "", Experience: String = "") {
    self.Rank = Rank
    self.Level = Level
    self.Experience = Experience
    }
}

var rsn: String = ""

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var Total = SkillStats()

@IBOutlet weak var totalXP: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var totalLevel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var totalRank: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var getrsn: UITextField!
@IBAction func rsnButton(_ sender: Any) {
rsn = getrsn.text!

rsn = rsn.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
rsn = rsn.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "%2D")

print(rsn)

//let rsn = "Real%20Nice"
 let jsonUrlString = "http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=" + rsn
 guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else
 {return}

 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, repsonse, err) in

 guard let data = data else {return}

 let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
 //print(dataAsString)

 let result = dataAsString?.components(separatedBy: [",","\n"])

 //comment this block
 //Total.Rank = result![0]
 //Total.Level = result![1]
 //Total.Experience = result![2]


  self.Total = SkillStats(Rank: result![0], Level: result![1], Experience: result![2])

 //printing stats to console
  print("Total Rank: " + self.Total.Rank)
  print("Total Level: " + self.Total.Level)
  print("Total Experience: " + self.Total.Experience)
 }.resume()

totalRank.text = "Rank: " + Total.Rank
totalLevel.text = "Level: " + Total.Level
totalXP.text = "XP: " + Total.Experience
}
```

Comment: Press button once and wait for new seconds as you are making api call it will take some time to get data from server and update your label text. let me know is it working or not.

Comment: I've got it to work now with your advice and using DispatchQue. Is there any way to pass DispatchQue a length of time less than a second? Thank you so much!

Comment: means do you want to want for few seconds before calling api ?

Comment: Here's the new bit of code.


   'DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
      self.totalRank.text = "Rank: " + self.Total.Rank
      self.totalLevel.text = "Level: " + self.self.Total.Level
      self.totalXP.text = "XP: " + self.Total.Experience
    })'
Is it possible to pass it a value less than 1 second? I'd like the wait time to be as little as possible.

Comment: Do you want to wait for few seconds before calling api using DispatchQueue?

Comment: I'm using DispatchQue to do the waiting for me

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Press button once and wait for new seconds as you are making api call it will take some time to get data from server and update your label text.

**Updated**

To updated your labels after few seconds you can do like below:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {

            self.totalRank.text = "Rank: " + self.Total.Rank
            self.totalLevel.text = "Level: " + self.self.Total.Level
            self.totalXP.text = "XP: " + self.Total.Experience
        }
```

> PS - yes, you can pass second value less then 1 as above code.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @zjgt37 Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.